# active class in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

sorry to ask. I have a button, then I add an active class when I click it, but when I click it all the buttons become active, how do I fix it?
this is the code

```js
  <div className="">
          {category.items.length === 0 ? (
            <div>There is no property at this categories</div>
          ) : (
            category.items.map((item, index2) => {
              return (
                <div key={`category-${index1}-item-${index2}`}>
                  {buttons.map((buttonLabel, i) => (
                    <button
                      key={i}
                      name={buttonLabel}
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, i)}
                      className={
                        i === clickedId
                          ? 'py-4 pl-3 customButton active '
                          : 'customButton py-4 pl-3'
                      }
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </button>
                  ))}
                </div>
              );
            })
          )}
        </div>
```

and this is code when button called

```js
<ButtonCategory
          data={category.categories}
          buttons={[category.categories]}
          doSomethingAfterClick={printButtonLabel}
        />
```

Comment: Please show `handleClick`

Comment: Also: where's `clickedId` coming from. Is it a state variable?

Comment: FWIW: Using the array index for this is usually not best practice (similarly for the `key` property). Unless `buttonLabel` isn't unique, I'd suggest using that. But what you have should work assuming `clickedId` is set to `i` by `handleClick`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Separately: I'd suggest not repeating the classes that don't change, it's too easy to edit one of them later and miss the other. Instead: ```className={`py-4 pl-3 customButton ${i === clickedId ? "active" : ""}`}```

Comment: this  is handle click and state clickedId

`const [clickedId, setClickedId] = useState(-1);
  const handleClick = (event, id) => {
    setClickedId(id);
    doSomethingAfterClick(event);
  };` 
@Viet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning the same set of buttons for each item. there are better ways to do this but with you current setup this should work:

```
  buttons.map((buttonLabel, i) => {
    const key = `${index2}.${i}`
    return (
    <button
      key={key}
      name={buttonLabel}
      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, key)}
      className={
        key === clickedId
          ? "py-4 pl-3 customButton active "
          : "customButton py-4 pl-3"
      }
    >
      {item.name}
    </button>
  )});
```

just don't forget to initialize your clickedId state as null or undefned instead of number

Answer (score 0):

youd should set index of the clicked button as clickedId in handleClick function. so your handleClick function must be like this

```
const handleClick = (event, i) => {
    setClickedId(i)
    // other logic
}
```

Comment: I did before. like this
`const handleClick = (event, id) => {
    setClickedId(id);
    doSomethingAfterClick(event);
  };`

Comment: you didd'nt put your entire code. but I guess you have some equal index for buttons. you should set clickedId something like this: ``${index1}${index2}${i}``